# Formula for number of pairs that can be made from $n$ items

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If I have
> $$\begin{align}
> 1 \text{ item}\phantom{s} &= \phantom{1}0 \text{ pair}\phantom{s} \\ 
> 2 \text{ items} &= \phantom{1}1 \text{ pair}\phantom{s} \\
> 3 \text{ items} &= \phantom{1}3 \text{ pairs} \\ 
> 4 \text{ items} &= \phantom{1}6 \text{ pairs} \\
> 5 \text{ items} &= 10 \text{ pairs} \\ 
> 6 \text{ items} &= 15 \text{ pairs}
> \end{align}$$
> and so on. How about if I have $n$ items? How many pairs can be made?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could also phrase this question "how many ways are there to pick two elements from a set of size $n$". We can answer this using the mathematics of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). In general, if we want to choose $k$ elements from a set of size $n$, there are
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
n \\
k
\end{pmatrix} := \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$
ways of doing so. In the case of $k=2$, we have
$$
\textrm{# of pairs} = \begin{pmatrix}
n \\
2
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$

You may also recognise $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ as the sum of the first $(n-1)$ integers. Can you think where this relationship might come from?